# How to pass Babel7 config file path to mocha and gulp-mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, mocha.js, babeljs

In Babel7 we have `babel.config.js` file. The path to this file we can pass via `configFile` or `config-file` argument, as I see in internet. However, I couldn't make mocha and gulp-mocha read `babel.config.js`.

This the way I run mocha:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./foo.spec.js --compilers js:@babel/register
```

This is the way I run gulpMocha

```
pipe(gulpMocha({
        reporter: 'spec',
        require: [
            '@babel/preset-env',
        ]
}))
```

How to pass Babel7 config file path to mocha and gulp-mocha?

If it is not possible for both of them, then, at least for one.

Comment: Which errors do you have with the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was suggested [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3724#issuecomment-463685833). 
For example, if project structure is like this:

```
Project
|-module1
|-module2
|-babel.config.js
```

And we want to test `module1`. We create `register.js` file in `Project/module1` with the following content:

```
require("@babel/register")({
  rootMode: "upward"
});
```

After that in `Project/module1` we run mocha this way: `mocha --require register.js` and `babel.config.js` will be found by babel.